# Change Date Format in sharepoint text box

Tags: javascript, datetime, sharepoint

I have text box (Single line text) in sharepoint form which used to capture received date time in the below format "**mmm dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss Am/Pm**" without quotes, i want to convert this as "**dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss Am/Pm**"

It should change automatically during **Keyup** or **lost focus** event.

javascript or Jquery script required for this.

Comment: use string.replace method

Comment: any suggested code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

Code:

```
var str = "mm dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss Am/Pm";
var words = new Array();
words = str.split(/(?:,| )+/);
let final_string = words[1] +  '/' + words[0] + '/' + words[2] + ' ' + words[3] + ' ' + words[4] ;
console.log(final_string)
```